# Callback before association is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have to set the table name of an associated model (limesurvey), because the table name is dynamic and depends on an attribute (survey_id) of the model (task).

My current implementation sets the table name, when the task is initialized:

```
class task < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :setTablename
  has_one :limesurvey

  def setTablename
    Limesurvey.table_name = "lime_survey_#{self.survey_id}"
  end
end
```

This implementation works, but it has the disadvantage, that the setTablename-method is called for every task, although it isn't needed.

How can I execute setTablename only before the association limesurvey is loaded?

Comment: Ewww! Looks like you can never have more than one `Limesurvey` open at a time: if you do, they'll save to each others' tables and it'll be super hard to debug. Anyway. Rails is built for a one-to-one model-to-table relationship, and trying to work against it will only end in headache and heartache. Consider moving all surveys into a single table indexed by a `survey_id` column, and then Rails will play a whole lot better with your database.

Comment: Yeah, fiddling with global settings is probably a super bad idea. I would really avoid doing this and use a proper sharding library instead.

Comment: Thanks for your warnings. I'll immediately change my code. Martin suggests using an instance variable in task instadt: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14326245/1386952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat: I agree that you are taking on a sea of troubles as the commenters have mentioned.  Further, this will likely be worse, since before at lease setTablename was getting called for every task.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :limesurvey

  def lime_survey
    @table_name || = (Limesurvey.table_name = "lime_survey_#{self.survey_id}")

    limesurvey
  end
end
```

This defines a version of limesurvey with an underscore, but checks first if the table name has been set.  Call lime_survey instead of limesurvey, and you will have the effect you asked for.

Similar to the approach suggested by Andy.  However, although the association is just a method, I'm not sure you can redefine it and call super, since it's not a method in the parent class (or module).

Comment: You can call `super` because it *is* in an included module. ActiveRecord defines all its "magic" methods (attributes, associations, etc) in a dynamically-generated module (accessed via [`generated_feature_methods`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-generated_feature_methods)).

Comment: Thanks. So `@table_name || = (Limesurvey.table_name = "lime_survey_#{self.survey_id}")` set an instance variable in task, only if @table_name wasn't set. And because it's an instance variable, the mentioned problem with calling `Limesurvey` wouldn't arise?

Comment: It will be called the first time lime_survey is called, and then only once, but it will not be called if the lime_survey getter is not referenced.

Comment: Thanks for the information @AndyH.  These things depend upon the details of the ActiveRecord implementation, and such things are not well documented.

Comment: @Christian As Marlin said at the start of the answer, this does not avoid any of the problems that have been mentioned - indeed it could make things worse. The issue I outlined in my answer, where you can save records into the wrong table, still exists with this approach.

Comment: @Christian, yes you are worried about efficiency, but have adopted an very unclean cumbersome, error prone design.  Write a clean, direct, obvious design, and leave performance as an after though only when poor performance is encountered.

Comment: I'm not worrying about efficiency. The database design is specified by [Limesurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/) und I can't merge the lime_survey_* tables, because the table structures are different for each survey.

Comment: If you are not worried about efficiency, why not call set table every time a task is initialized?  It would be clearer cleaner code than sometimes the table is set, other times it is not yet set, then there is code which tests if it has not been set to set it, but only to run once.

Answer (score 0):

Associations are just methods defined in a module that is included in your model, so you can override them as you would other methods

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :limesurvey

  def limesurvey
    # do something here...

    super
  end
end
```

However, as people have mentioned in the comments on the question, what you're doing is a really bad idea. What would happen if you have two tasks available at once, and attempted to access the `limesurvey` on both of them?

```
t1 = Task.first
t2 = Task.last

l1 = t1.limesurvey
l2 = t2.limesurvey

l1.update_attributes(foo: "bar")
# Oops... saves into the wrong table...
```

Even if you manage to avoid doing this explicitly anywhere in your whole app, if you have two concurrent requests it could potentially happen accidentally!